# Get List of Tuples or Lists of minimum distances nad index of minimum distances

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe column of n-dimensional arrays (let's call it data) and a list of n-dimensional arrays (let's call it means).  For each item in the dataframe, I'm trying to grab the distance between the item in the dataframe and closest item in the means list as well as the index of the minimum in the list.  I'm able to get the minimum distances using the following:

```
distances = [min([spatial.distance.cosine(i.ravel(),j.ravel()) for i in means]) 
                             for j in data['data']]
```

However I'm struggling to expand this to include the index of the element in the means list as well.  I've tried enumerating the means list, but I'm not sure where to put the count iterator.  Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.argmin` instead of `min`. Also, I think `spatial.distance` accept numpy array. So you could probably do:

```
idx = np.argmin(spatial.distance.cosine(data['data'].values[:, None],
                                        means[None, :]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to replace the inner loop and use the `apply` method to replace the outer loop:

```
distances = data['data'].apply(lambda j: np.min(map(lambda i: spatial.distance.cosine(i.ravel(), j.ravel()), means))))
```

if you want to get the minimum index simply use `np.argmin` instead of `min` or `np.min` as pointed out in another answer. Or replace the `np.min` by `list` to get all the distances, then apply both functions separetely

Comment: Is there a quick way to compute this?  This creates generator objects that I have to cast as a list which seems to take a while.